# Why is guava's verifyNotNull not @Nonnull?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, guava, nullable

Guava's `verifyNotNull` takes a nullable parameter that is expected to always be nonnull at runtime, and asserts the claim.

What bothers me, though, is that the method isn't annotated with @Nonnull.  It seems like it should, but in addition, this lacking is causing IntelliJ IDEA to throw a warning whenever I use its return value for a @Nonnull return value or variable.

Is there a reason for this method to not reflect its contract with an annotation?

Comment: Probably so they can test it with `verifyNotNull(null)`.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in IntelliJ not respecting @ParametersAreNonnullByDefault.